# Was there a period of global warming before the start of the last ice age?

Tags: climate-change, ice-age

I am curious to know if there was a period of global warming that took place before the start of the last ice age and I would like to know how long this period of global warming lasted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an interglacial befor the last glaciation:
[image]

> glacial–interglacial cycles last ~100,000 years (middle, black line) and consist of stepwise cooling events followed by rapid warmings, as seen in this time series inferred from hydrogen isotopes in the Dome Fuji ice core from Antarctica

[NOAA](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/abrupt-climate-change/Glacial-Interglacial%20Cycles)